# Stuffed Dumpling Made with Rice Flour

Tags: substitutions, asian-cuisine, gluten-free, dumplings

I have been working with rice flour to make homemade stuffed dumplings and have been able to improve my current recipe greatly except for one thing. I am stump as to how I can have the dough stretchier.

Currently the way I make the dough is: 2 cups rice flour, 2/3 cups potato starch, 1/3 cup tapioca flour, 1 tbsp flax seeds, 1 tsp baking soda, 1 tsp salt, 1 cup of water and 1 avocado (or 47 grams of spinach/1 Korean sweet potato) mixed, 2 tbsp sesame oil, and 1 tbsp olive oil.

So my question is: How can I make this dough have the same stretchy consistency like all purpose flour without using xanthan gum?

Comment: "the **same** stretchy consistency" - that stretchy-ness is specifically because of gluten.  You may have to settle for "relatively similar" or "some." I'd think there would be some gluten-free pizza doughs that try to emulate it, since that's a hallmark of thinner pizza crusts. Maybe see how those recipes (minus yeast) stack up.

Comment: If you're not trying to make gluten-free dumplings, why not add a spoonful of gluten flour to your mix? A small amount shouldn't change the taste (unless your sense of taste is *very* sensitive). You need to then knead your dough to develop the gluten strands to provide elasticity.

Answer (score 2):

Use boiling hot water to gelatinize the  starch in the rice.

Instead of a cup of room-temperature water, use boiling water to mix with the rice flour. It will make the dough stretchable. You might need some more rice flour to use as coating to prevent sticking. This link of a recipe describes it best : http://kitchentigress.blogspot.sg/2011/09/how-to-make-soon-kueh.html

Note:

I added more information as requested by Doug.

Comment: You should elaborate a bit on your answer.